# Android custom triangle shape

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I have referred many StackOverflow questions regarding drawing triangle shapes.
is there a way to make this shape in xml?

[image]

Comment: a simple triangle yes, but I think with this one, You better should use image resource....

Comment: Your triangle above isn't simple.

Comment: could i only make circle and lines with this formation in xml? @Opiatefuchs

Comment: @mr.icetea could i only make circle and lines with this formation in xml?

Comment: You can do this for example: Your dotted line can be a stroke in your circle and here You have to give the attributes android:dashWidth="10px" & android:dashGap="10px", You have to play a little bit with this. ....but still....it is very hard to do this

Comment: if You are successful doing this, I think You should show Your solution as an answer, because it is a very interesting question. +1 for this question.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs ok Certainly.